# Stuck on this proof that $ord(f) = ord(g)$

Tags: differential-geometry, germs

Let $f, g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be smooth maps such that $f(a) = g(a') = 0$ and let $\tau, \sigma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be diffeomorphisms such that

$$ \tau \circ f = g \circ \sigma$$

Define $ord(f) = \min \{ n \in \mathbb N_{>0} \mid f^{(n)} (a) \neq 0\}$.

I am trying to show that $ord(f) = ord(g)$. I wanted to do induction but the induction step is broken since $ \tau \circ f = g \circ \sigma$ does not imply that there are diffeomorphisms $\phi, \pi$ such that

$ \phi \circ f' = g' \circ \pi$

Next I thought I could derive a closed form for the $n$-th derivative of $ \tau \circ f = g \circ \sigma$ but I can't see a pattern. The sums get rather long.

Now I am starting to wonder whether the thing I'm trying to show is even true. If it is I think the proof should be short and simple very unlike what I've tried so far.

> Does anyone have any ideas on whether this is true and if it is on how
>   to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with properly defining the function ${\rm ord}$. Given a sufficiently differentiable function $f: \>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ one defines
$${\rm ord\,}_a(f)=\inf\{n>0\>|\>f^{(n)}(a)\ne0\}\ .$$

Note that ${\rm ord}$ needs two inputs. In your question you introduced ${\rm ord\,}_a(f)$ but forgot to pin down the point $a_*$ at which ${\rm ord\,}_{a_*}(g)$ should be computed. *This has to be the point* $\sigma(a)$, because otherwise it is easy to give  counterexamples, e.g., the following:

Assume $a'\ne a$ and put $$f(x):=(x-a)^2, \qquad g(x):=(x-a)^2-(a'-a)^2,\qquad \sigma:={\rm id},\qquad \tau (x):=x-(a'-a)^2\ .$$
Then one has $\tau\circ f=g\circ\sigma$, $f(a)=g(a')=0$, but
$${\rm ord\,}_a(f)=2,\qquad {\rm ord\,}_{a'}(g)=1\ ,$$
since $g'(a')=2(a'-a)\ne0$.

(For this reason in my original answer I tacitly assumed $a'=\sigma(a)$ and then $a=a'=0$, which made $\sigma$ and $\tau$ diffeomorphisms with $\sigma(0)=\tau(0)=0$.)

Now the positive result: The function ${\rm ord}$ satisfies a sort of chain rule:
$${\rm ord\,}_a(g\circ f)={\rm ord\,}_{f(a)}(g)\cdot{\rm ord\,}_a(f)\ .$$
*Proof.* We may assume
$$a=f(a)=0,\qquad {\rm ord\,}_a(f)=p\geq1,\qquad {\rm ord\,}_{f(a)}(g)=q\geq1\ .$$
The following principle is an immediate consequence of Taylor's theorem:
$${\rm ord\,}_0(f)=m<\infty\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad f(x)=x^m\bigl(\alpha+r(x)\bigr)\quad  {\rm with} \quad  \alpha\ne0, \ \lim_{x\to0}r(x)=0\ .$$
So there are constants $\alpha\ne0$, $\beta\ne0$, and  functions $x\mapsto r_1(x)$,  $y\mapsto r_2(y)$ with $\lim_{x\to0}r_1(x)=\lim_{y\to0}r_2(y)=0$ such that
$$f(x)=x^p\bigl(\alpha+r_1(x)\bigr),\qquad g(y)=y^q\bigl(\beta+r_2(y)\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that
$$g\bigl( f(x)\bigr)=x^{pq}\bigl(\alpha+r_1(x)\bigr)^q\bigl(\beta+r_2\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)=x^{pq}\bigl(a^q\beta+r(x)\bigr)$$
for some function $x\mapsto r(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to0}r(x)=0.\qquad\square$

Since diffeomorphisms $\sigma:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ have ${\rm ord\,}_a(\sigma)=1$ at all points $a$ your original conjecture, interpreted correctly, follows.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. At least I now know that the statement is actually true!

Comment: Did someone downvote this answer? If so, why? Is it wrong?

Comment: When you say that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are "diffeomorphisms near $0$", do you mean that $\sigma (0) = \tau (0) = 0$? I fail to see how you get this only from the hypotheses. As I have written in my own answer, if $\sigma (a) \ne a$ (you have taken $a = a'$) then the OP's statement is false. Strangely, you do not encounter this in your considerations.

Comment: @Alex M. : My answer was more general than the OP had in mind. Your editing has degraded it, but I left it at that. Assuming $a=a'=0$ is of course no restriction of generality. The OP wrote ${\rm ord}(f)$ instead of ${\rm ord\,}_a(f)$ (or similar) when defining the order of a zero.

Comment: Your assumption indeed does not restrict generality, but under it how do you prove $\sigma (0) = 0$ only from $\tau ( f (0) ) = g ( \sigma (0) )$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$?

Comment: Concerning the edit, I have only replaced $\Bbb R ^n$ by $\Bbb R$, otherwise the problem would no longer hold together ($g$ would be defined on $\Bbb R ^n$, while $f$ would be defined on $\Bbb R$, so you could no longer have $a = a'$, and plenty of other complications). If you find my edit abusive, please roll it back. Still, I think that it fixes things, not damages them. I am not a "professional downvoter", I just think that your proof omits some significant details.

Comment: @Alex M. : In my answer both $f$ and $g$ were defined on ${\mathbb R}^n$ (superfluously, of course). I had explicitly $\sigma:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$ and $\tau:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$. – That's my last word on this matter.

Comment: Dear Christian Blatter, many thanks for your answer. I am still studying it. Would you point me to a reference where I can read up on the $C$ you can find to bound the diffeomorphisms from below? It's not clear to me why it can be chosen to be greater equals $1$. The only thing that I do understand there is that because the diffeos are continuous they are bounded (on the closure of some open ball containing $0$).

Comment: @astudent: See the appendix to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: In the equation where you bound $g$ using $f$, isn't there a $\tau$ missing? It seems to me that since $g = \tau \circ f \circ \sigma^{-1}$ there should also be a $\tau$. But perhaps I am mistaken...

Comment: In the appendix I am trying to understand why $|\sigma' (x)|$ can be made $\le C$ on a suitably small neighbourhood. It seems to me that if $\sigma'$ was for example the function $-x^2 + 2$ then this would not hold. I'm now trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: I got it: sorry, I didn't the factor of $2$ before the maximum. The other thing with $\tau$ is still not clear to me tough.

Comment: Thank you, I see you replaced the previous proof with a new proof (which at first glance appears neater). Just for the sake of my personal mathematical education I would still like to understand the inequality in the previous proof where you bound $g$ using $f$ and $C$. Concretely, my question remains as to whether $\tau$ is missing from that equation or not. Please would you be so kind as to tell me if the inequality indeed needed a $\tau$ or not?

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not define $ord(g)$; I shall presume it to be like $ord(f)$
but with $a$ replaced by $a'$.

Second, *your statement is true if and only if $\sigma(a) = a'$* (read the proof for $org(g) = 1$ to understand why).

Third, we shall make essential use of the following formula which generalizes Leibniz's formula:

$$(f_1 f_2 \dots f_n) ^{(p)} = \sum \limits _{i_1 + i_2 + \dots + i_n = p} \frac {p!} {i_1 ! i_2 ! \dots i_n !} f_1 ^{(i_1)} f_2 ^{(i_2)} \dots f_n ^{(i_n)}$$

(if you want, it is easy to prove it by induction).

Note that since $\tau$ is a diffeomorphism, we may invert it, getting $f = \tau ^{-1} \circ g \circ \sigma$.

Let us see what happens when $ord(g) = 1$ (i.e. $g'(a') \ne 0$). We have

$$f'(a) = (\tau ^{-1})' \circ g \circ \sigma (a) \cdot g' \circ \sigma (a) \cdot \sigma ' (a) = (\tau ^{-1})' (g(a')) \cdot g' (a') \cdot \sigma ' (a) = \\ (\tau ^{-1})' (0) \cdot g' (a') \cdot \sigma ' (a) .$$

Note that since $\tau ^{-1}$ and $\sigma$ are diffeomorphisms, their derivatives cannot cancel anywhere; since $g'(a') \ne 0$ by assumption, this gives $f'(a) \ne 0$, i.e. $ord(f) = 1$.

Now let us see the induction step: assume $ord(g) = n \ge 2$. We shall prove that $f^{(k)} (a) = 0 \; \forall k<n$ and $f^{(n)} (a) \ne 0$.

Note that

$$f^{(k)} (a) = (f')^{(k-1)} (a) = ((\tau ^{-1})' \circ g \circ \sigma \cdot g' \circ \sigma \cdot \sigma ') ^{(k-1)} (a) = \sum \limits _{i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = k-1} \frac {(k-1)!} {i_1 ! i_2 ! i_3 !} \big( (\tau ^{-1})' \circ g \circ \sigma \big) ^{(i_1)} \cdot \big( g' \circ \sigma \big) ^{(i_2)} \cdot \big( \sigma ' \big) ^{(i_3)} .$$

Now stop calculating and think: in the above sum, the only derivatives of $g$ showing up will be of order *at most* $k$, because $i_1$ and $i_2$ can go up to *at most* $k-1$. Since $ord(g) = n > k$, all these derivatives are $0$, from which follows $f^{(k)} (a) = 0 \; \forall k<n$.

In order to see that $f^{(n)} (a)\ne 0$ we shall use the same formula above, but with $k$ replaced by $n$:

$$f^{(n)} (a) = (f')^{(n-1)} (a) = ((\tau ^{-1})' \circ g \circ \sigma \cdot g' \circ \sigma \cdot \sigma ') ^{(n-1)} (a) = \sum \limits _{i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = n-1} \frac {(n-1)!} {i_1 ! i_2 ! i_3 !} \big( (\tau ^{-1})' \circ g \circ \sigma \big) ^{(i_1)} \cdot \big( g' \circ \sigma \big) ^{(i_2)} \cdot \big( \sigma ' \big) ^{(i_3)} .$$

The only non-zero term will be the one with $i_2 = n-1$ (which implies $i_1 = i_3 = 0$), which is $(g' \circ \sigma) ^{(n-1)} (a)$. Now, you either understand at a glance what happens here, or you can use induction once more to show that, in fact, this is equal to $( g^{(n)} \circ \sigma ) (a) = g^{(n)} (a') \ne 0 $ by assumption. Therefore, $f^{(n)} (a) = g^{(n)} (a') \ne 0$, so $ord(f) = n$.